# Scrolling gallery off-centered in HTML JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tailwind-css

I am making a gallery full of images from my portfolio where you can click a right and left arrow to change the image in focus horizontally. The in-active divs are blurred and smaller in height, while the active div is clear and taller in height. All of the divs are contained inside of a flex div with a gap. All of the style classes are using tailwind css, and I am using jquery to rotate the images.

I want to make the active image in the very center of the screen and the scroll container moves left and right with absolute value to do so.

That works but its not completely centered, its just off every time. Is there a better way to shift it to make that scrolling more accurate?

This is the HTML using tailwind css:

```
            <section class="overflow-hidden font-general relative w-screen py-12 h-[450px] mt-[60px]">
                <div id="rightScroll" class="absolute z-10 rounded-full cursor-pointer left-10 flex -rotate-90 justify-center items-center top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 w-14 h-14 bg-white"></div>
                <div id="leftScroll" class="absolute z-10 rounded-full cursor-pointer right-10 rotate-90 flex justify-center items-center top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 w-14 h-14 bg-white">
                </div>
                <div id="scrollContainer" class="w-max absolute h-[450px] flex items-center gap-x-20">
                    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-col justify-end" style="height: 350px; filter: blur(5px); width: calc(100vw*0.65); padding: 25px; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 1.25rem; background: linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 20%, rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.2) 60%, rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.2) 100%), url(/images/project_thumb.webp); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">
                        <span class="uppercase text-white text-4xl font-normal" style="opacity: 0%;">Health Tech Website</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-col justify-end" style="height: 450px; width: calc(100vw*0.65); padding: 25px; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 1.25rem; background: linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 20%, rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.2) 60%, rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.2) 100%), url(/images/project_thumb1.webp); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">
                        <span class="uppercase text-white text-4xl font-normal" style="opacity: 100%;">Health Tech Website</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-col justify-end" style="height: 350px; filter: blur(5px); width: calc(100vw*0.65); padding: 25px; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 1.25rem; background: linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 20%, rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.2) 60%, rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.2) 100%), url(/images/project_thumb2.webp); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">
                        <span class="uppercase text-white text-4xl font-normal" style="opacity: 0%;">Health Tech Website</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

This is the JQuery used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const scrollContainer = $("#scrollContainer");
    const divs = scrollContainer.children("div");
    const divWidth = divs.first().width() + 20; // Assuming all divs have the same width
    let currentIndex = 0;

    function updateDivs() {
        divs.each(function(index, element) {
            const isActive = index === currentIndex;
            const height = isActive ? 450 : 350;
            const blur = isActive ? "blur(0)" : "blur(5px)";
            const opacity = isActive ? 1 : 0;

            $(element).css({
                height: `${height}px`,
                filter: blur,
            }).find(".text-white").css("opacity", opacity);
        });

        // Calculate offset to center the active div
        const centerOffset = scrollContainer.width() / 4;
        const activeDivCenterOffset = currentIndex * divWidth + divWidth / 2;

        const scrollOffset = centerOffset - activeDivCenterOffset;
        scrollContainer.css("transform", `translateX(${scrollOffset}px)`);
    }

    $("#rightScroll").click(function() {
        currentIndex = Math.max(currentIndex - 1, 0);
        updateDivs();
    });

    $("#leftScroll").click(function() {
        currentIndex = Math.min(currentIndex + 1, divs.length - 1);
        updateDivs();
    });

    updateDivs();
});
```